# problem with inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question:** I want to solve $0<1−an/(mb^2)e^{−r(T−t)}<1$, where $r, a, b, T, t>0$.

The solution is that either $$an\leq mb^2$$ or $$mb^2\leq an\leq mb^2e^{rT}$$ and $$t< T − (\ln(an) − \ln(mb^2 ))/r$$.

**My Attempt:** My thoughts are that the first part $0<1−\frac{an}{mb^2}e^{−r(T−t)}$ gives me $an \leq mb^2$ because $e^{−r(T−t)}>0$, so I have the first part. The second part  $1−\frac{an}{mb^2}e^{−r(T−t)}<1$ does not give me useful information since $\frac{an}{mb^2}e^{−r(T−t)}>0$ always.

How do I get the other half of the solution ( $mb^2\leq an\leq mb^2e^{rT}$ and $t< T − (\ln(an) − \ln(mb^2 ))/r$)?

I also realise that the problem I have to solve reduces to solving $xy<1$ where both $x,y>0$.

---

Merged from: [tricky inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/tricky-inequality)

How do I go about solving $0<1−\frac{an}{mb^2}e^{−r(T−t)}<1$, where a,b,T>t>0? I have been stuck here for some time now.

Comment: Your second sentence effectively says X OR Y AND Z. Do you mean (X OR Y) AND Z or do you mean X OR (Y AND Z)?

Comment: For the first part, we have to also use $e^{-r(T-t)} \le 1$ (assuming that T>t, which you haven't stated)

Comment: Casebash, I mean $X$ OR ($Y$ AND $Z)$ and you are right $T>t$, sorry I did not state that.

Comment: Which are the variables?

Comment: I am looking for all the possibilities of $t$ in terms of $a,b,m, T$ or $a$ in terms of $b,m,T$

Comment: Can you explain that in the question?

Comment: And what have you tried? It should at least be obvious how to get it down to an inequality for $e^{-r(T-t)}$.

Comment: What conditions are set on *m* and *n*?

Answer (score 6):

There are many unnecessary variables. Let

$$\alpha = \frac{an}{mb^2}.\qquad(1)$$

Then the inequality becomes

$$ 0 < 1 - \alpha e^{-r (T - t)} < 1 $$

The first obvious step is perform “1 −” on every parts,

$$ 1 > \alpha e^{-r (T-t)} > 0 $$

Since the exponential function's range is positive and < 1 (since *r* > 0 and *T* > *t* > 0), we can ensure *α* is positive.

If 0 < *α* ≤ 1, then every *t* will satisfy the inequality (the first solution).

So assume *α* > 1. Now it's pretty obvious on how to solve *t* in terms of *r*, *T* and *α*. Substitute (1) again to get back *a*, *n*, *m* and *b*.

Things you may consider:

- *e<sup>x</sup>* is strictly increasing.

Comment: partly answered, how about $an \leq mb^2e^{rT}$? I dont get it the $t$ is gone.

Comment: @Vaolter: How did you arrive at that? Also, do not expand *α* until you've reached the step *t* > (or <) something.

Comment: @KennyTM thats the solution i want to get.

Comment: @Vaolter: It is to ensure the solution $t < T - \frac1r\ln \alpha$ is consistent with the condition $t < T$.

Comment: @KennyTM will you tell me how to get $an≤mb^2e^{rT}$?

Comment: @Vaolter: Sorry that's not because of the condition *t* < *T*, but *t* > 0. So you get $0 < t < T - \frac1r \ln\alpha$. Ignore the *t* and solve for *α*. (And I don't think $an = mb^2 e^{rT} is possible.)