# tricky inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/problem-with-inequality)

How do I go about solving $0<1−\frac{an}{mb^2}e^{−r(T−t)}<1$, where a,b,T>t>0? I have been stuck here for some time now.